# Binance Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER

Tags: java, binance

I am using binance java API and trying to issue a limit sell.

But i keep receiving error:

> com.binance.api.client.exception.BinanceApiException: Filter failure:
> PRICE_FILTER

I was searching for the reason that could cause this problem and found out different coins demands different precision. However, how do I find out this precision?

when i do for example

```
client.getExchangeInfo().getSymbolInfo("symbolname").getQuotePrecision()
```

and then try to set my set price of 1.5 of buy price e.g something like:

```
        int precision = client.getExchangeInfo().getSymbolInfo(TOKEN).getQuotePrecision()
        NewOrderResponse res=client.newOrder(marketBuy(TOKEN,amount).newOrderRespType(NewOrderResponseType.FULL));
        String buyPrice = res.getFills().get(0).getPrice();
        String sellPrice = calculateSellprice(buyPrice, 1.3,precision);

        private String calculateSellprice(String buyPrice, double i,int precision) {
            return String.format("%." + precision + "f" , Double.parseDouble(buyPrice) * i);
        }
```

I still receive the same error. What is the correct way to set the price then?

Comment: First thing i should suggest to try with BigDecimal instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

to get the precision information and other filter information related to different filter errors such as PRICE_FILTER and PRICE_PERCENTAGE you need to call the /api/v3/exchangeInfo endpoint. https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information. If you see the response data in there you will find the precision and also a filters property that has all the specific filter properties you need to abide by based on the pair you give it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get filter from response not Precision and price have to be range of this filter.